# Typescript Mongoose - methods / static functions not being called [ Kubernetes - Docker ]

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I've faced an issue when using `mongodb < TypeScript >` in `Kubernetes - Docker`.
I added a **middleware** on ***save*** and a **static** function on ***Model***. It's not being called when It's used. None of them does work **[ Middleware - Static function ]** .

User Model :

```
import { model, Schema, Model, Document } from "mongoose";
import { Password } from "../service/Password";
/**
 * @interface UserAttr
 * @description It helps the User Model in the moment of being createed
 */

interface UserAttrs {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

/**
 * @interface UserModel
 * @description It helps the method of the user being detective on its own model
 */

interface UserModel extends Model<UserDocument> {
  build(attrs: UserAttrs): UserDocument;
}

/**
 * @interface UserDocument
 * @description It helps the document of the user to work more efficiently
 */

export interface UserDocument extends Document {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
}

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const User = model<UserDocument, UserModel>("User", userSchema);

userSchema.statics.build = function (attrs: UserAttrs) {
  return new User(attrs);
};

userSchema.pre(
  "save",
  async function (this: UserDocument, next): Promise<void> {
    console.log("Saving . . . ");
    // const self = this as UserDocument;
    if (this.isModified("password")) {
      const hashedPassword = await Password.toHash(this.get("password"));
      this.set("password", hashedPassword);
    }
    next();
  }
);

export { User };
```

The place where they're getting used:

```
import { Router, Response, Request } from "express";
import { body, validationResult } from "express-validator";
import { BadRequestError } from "../../errors/BadRequestError";
import { RequestValidationError } from "../../errors/RequestValidationError";
import { User } from "../../models/user.model";

const router: Router = Router();

router.post(
  "/api/users/signup",
  [
    body("email")
      .not()
      .isEmpty()
      .withMessage("Email Field is empty. fill it please")
      .trim()
      .isEmail()
      .normalizeEmail()
      .withMessage("Email is not valid. "),
    body("password")
      .notEmpty()
      .withMessage("Password Field is empty. fill it please")
      .trim()
      .isLength({ min: 4, max: 12 })
      .withMessage("Password length is 4 - 12 characters"),
  ],
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      throw new RequestValidationError(errors.array());
    }

    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const existingUser = await User.findOne({
      email,
    });

    if (existingUser) {
      throw new BadRequestError("Email in use");
    }

    const user = User.build({
      email,
      password,
    });

    await user.save();
    res.status(201).json(user);
  }
);

export { router as signUpRouter };
```

**Hint:** I checked the model itself `[ new User({...}) ]` and worked as expected. I don't know why they're not working with the **`middleware and static function`**

Answer (score 0):

After a long time, I found the solution of the above-mentioned error-prone module myself.

**Solution:** The error was the sequence of the codes written above. The model has to be all the way down to be recognizable.It won't react to the `middlewares`, `Statics` and `Methods` at all.Make sure the `Model` is all the way down just right before the export when you set some of the previous features.

**The could has to be like the following steps:**

```
import { model, Schema, Model, Document } from "mongoose";
import { Password } from "../service/Password";
/**
 * @interface UserAttr
 * @description It helps the User Model in the moment of being createed
 */

interface UserAttrs {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

/**
 * @interface UserModel
 * @description It helps the method of the user being detective on its own model
 */

interface UserModel extends Model<UserDocument> {
  build(attrs: UserAttrs): UserDocument;
}

/**
 * @interface UserDocument
 * @description It helps the document of the user to work more efficiently
 */

export interface UserDocument extends Document {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
}

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

userSchema.statics.build = function (attrs: UserAttrs) {
  return new User(attrs);
};

userSchema.pre(
  "save",
  async function (this: UserDocument, next): Promise<void> {
    console.log("Saving . . . ");
    // const self = this as UserDocument;
    if (this.isModified("password")) {
      const hashedPassword = await Password.toHash(this.get("password"));
      this.set("password", hashedPassword);
    }
    next();
  }
);

const User = model<UserDocument, UserModel>("User", userSchema);

export default User;
```